# Export Jar from eclipse for GitHub Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, file, maven, jar

I actually have a problem to export a fully running Jar File from Eclipse.

[Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/axet/play)

I had set up the Workspace like he did in the Video but when I want to export it to a running Jar File, I get a Jar file but it ends with an error that the `vlccore natives not found`. In eclipse the project works completely. Could someone please try to help me and give me an detailed Information how i can get a full running jar file?

Thanks in advance!